# How to define a map of volatile elements in cpp

Tags: c++, dictionary, volatile

I want to generate a map of mutex elements, which probably need to be volatile.
I am trying to define something of this sort:

```
typedef std::map<int key, volatile long mutex> tMutexMap;
tMutexMap myMutexMap;
```

and then use the simple map index, e.g.:

```
myMutexMap[10]=0;
myMutexMap[23]=1;
```

I'm using gcc 4.1.2. The gcc compiler doesn't like that code. I get an error

> no matching function for call to 'std::pair....'"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: typedef the volatile long and use that in the map definition?

Comment: This is a reduced test case: https://gist.github.com/3866187

Comment: peacemaker, tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can make volatile element in map. You can make volatile map but not value in map.
Map is implemented as binary tree. And there is complex algorithm to get value from this tree. Volatile said to compiler that it shouldn't optimize access to this variable. You can use volatile when you have direct access to variable. But in map you don't have such direct access.

Comment: You can in fact get direct access to the *value* stored in a map, but would need to take care that you're not getting copies.   

A map in which the value is `volatile` is broken for all the normal reasons that the use of `volatile` in user-space is.

Comment: So, what you're suggesting is that anything other than a c-style pre-allocated array would be too dangerous to use.

Answer (score 5):

C/C++'s `volatile` is not like `volatile` in some managed languages and has nothing to do with mutexes (see http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484). Depending on what you want to achieve consider using either [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) (or `boost::mutex` if you have a pre-C++11 standard library) or `std::atomic<YourPreferredIntergalType>`

Answer (score 0):

Why would the values need to be `volatile`? The impact of `volatile` has nothing to do with threads.

That said, the problem may be just the defaukt constructor which is implicitly used when using te subscript operator (you unfortunately truncated the error message so it's hard to tell). Try inserting readily built pairs of an appropriate type. For the look-up you'd need to use the `find()` member of the map.

Comment: And indeed, if this is a *mutex* in any normal understanding of the word, you would want it to behave with precisely the kind of semantics that `volatile` modified is used to hint are not present. 

If what is being stored in the map is in fact a semaphore lock-count (it sure does from the types), what is required is an atomic operation or (going lower level) a series of memory barriers around the reads and writes.  You would need to be very careful to ensure you are actually modifying the original copy in the map rather than a copy-by-value.